# 'ImageDraw' object has no attribute 'textbbox'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, word-cloud

I am working on a simple text mining project. When I tried to create a word-cloud I got this error:

`AttributeError: 'ImageDraw' object has no attribute 'textbbox'`

I have a dataset of News and their categories; to create a word-cloud I tried to preprocessing the text:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from textblob import Word
from wordcloud import WordCloud 

newsData = pd.read_csv("data.txt", sep= '\t', header=None, 
                       names=["Description", "Category", "Tags"],on_bad_lines='skip', 
                       engine='python' , encoding='utf-8')
#print(newsData.head())

newsData['Description'] =  newsData['Description'].apply(lambda x:  " ".join(x.lower() for x in x.split()))
newsData['Category'] =  newsData['Category'].apply(lambda x:  " ".join(x.lower() for x in x.split()))
newsData['Tags'] =  newsData['Tags'].apply(lambda x:  " ".join(x.lower() for x in x.split()))

# stopword filtering
stop = stopwords.words('english')
newsData['Description'] =  newsData['Description'].apply(lambda x: " ".join (x for x in x.split() if x not in stop))
#stemming

st = PorterStemmer()
newsData['Description'] =  newsData['Description'].apply(lambda x: " ".join ([st.stem(word) for word in x.split()]))
newsData['Category'] =  newsData['Category'].apply(lambda x: " ".join ([st.stem(word) for word in x.split()]))
newsData['Tags'] =  newsData['Tags'].apply(lambda x: " ".join ([st.stem(word) for word in x.split()]))

#lemmatize

newsData['Description'] =  newsData['Description'].apply(lambda x: " ".join ([Word(word).lemmatize() for word in x.split()]))
newsData['Category'] =  newsData['Category'].apply(lambda x: " ".join ([Word(word).lemmatize() for word in x.split()]))
newsData['Tags'] =  newsData['Tags'].apply(lambda x: " ".join ([Word(word).lemmatize() for word in x.split()]))
#print(newsData.head())


culture = newsData[newsData['Category'] == 'culture'].sample(n=200)
health = newsData[newsData['Category'] == 'health'].sample(n=200)
dataSample = pd.concat([culture, health],axis=0)

culturesmpl = culture[culture['Category'] == 'culture'].sample(n=200)
healthspml = health[health['Category'] == 'health'].sample(n=200)
#print(dataSample.head())

cultureSTR = culturesmpl.Description.str.cat()
healthSTR = healthspml.Description.str.cat()
#print(spam_str)
```

and then I tried to create wordcloud using WordCloud library

```
wordcloud_culture =  WordCloud(collocations= False, background_color='white' ).generate(cultureSTR)

# Plot
plt.imshow(wordcloud_culture, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

but after running this code I got the error:

```
  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wordcloud/wordcloud.py:508 in generate_from_frequencies
    box_size = draw.textbbox((0, 0), word, font=transposed_font, anchor="lt")

AttributeError: 'ImageDraw' object has no attribute 'textbbox'
```

do you know how can I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### History

The `ImageDraw.textsize()` method was deprecated in PIL version 9.2.0 and completely [removed](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deprecations.html#font-size-and-offset-methods) beginning with version 10.0.0 on 2023-07-01.

The `ImageDraw.textbbox()` method was [introduced](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.textbbox) in version 8.0.0 as a more robust solution.

### Example

If you are looking to simply replace one line of code, and you previously had

`text_width, text_height = ImageDraw.Draw(image).textsize(your_text, font=your_font)`

..then you could instead use

`_, _, text_width, text_height = ImageDraw.Draw(image).textbbox((0, 0), your_text, font=your_font)`

### Explanation

`textsize()` outputs dimensions for the *nominal* width and height of the text as a tuple: `(width, height)`.
`textbbox()` outputs the x and y extents of the bounding box as a tuple: `(left, top, right, bottom)`.

Starting the line with `_, _,` is a way to discard the first two elements of the output tuple.

Adding `(0, 0)` as the first argument in `textbbox()` tells it to anchor the bounding box at the origin.

Avoid relying on outdated libraries, and explore reasons for this change and why `textbbox()` is a more robust method!

Comment: one sad fact is that wordcloud itself is calling textsize() and not textbox(), not the OP code, nor is mine that has the same error.

Answer (score 3):

The textsize function is deprecated in Pillow 10.

Thus installing Pillow 9.5.0 will fix the issue:

```
pip3 install Pillow==9.5.0
```

Comment: I am using python 3.9, 3.10, 3.11 and 3.12 and sadly this does not resolve the error in any of the versions.

Answer (score 2):

I was installed pillow 7.1.1, then I upgrade it to 9.5.0. and then the error was gone!

so if you face the same problem you can fix with:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

Comment: No, that will break it. See the other answers.

Comment: This might have worked at one point in time, but will no longer work, do not upgrade pillow to resolve this error

Comment: This worked for me!